# Bluebird promisify Mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am only using Bluebird for few days, still I am confused.Here is the code I am working on :

```
router.route('/:name')
        .get(function (req, res) {
                var values = [];
                 Tag.findOneAsync({'name': req.params.name}, {urlId: 1, _id: 0}).then(function (data) {
                    data['urlId'].forEach(function (urlId) {
                        Urls.findByIdAsync(urlId).then(function (result) {
                            values.push(result);
                        }).catch(function (err) {
                            res.status(500).send(err);
                        });
                    });
                }).catch(function (err) {
                    res.status(500).send(err);
                });

                res.send(values);
     });
```

in this code, respond is empty `values` . So I tried to organize the code this way :

```
router.route('/:name')
        .get(function (req, res) {
            var  prom = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                var values = [];
                Tag.findOneAsync({'name': req.params.name}, {urlId: 1, _id: 0}).then(function (data) {
                    data['urlId'].forEach(function (urlId) {
                        Urls.findByIdAsync(urlId).then(function (result) {
                            values.push(result);

                        }).catch(function (err) {
                            reject(err);
                        });
                    });
                }).catch(function (err) {
                    reject(err);
                });
                resolve(values);
            });
            prom.then(function (values) {
                res.send(values);
            });
```

Still the result is same . So how do I organize the code , so I can get response , after completing `data['urlId'].forEach`  operation.

Comment: can you try adding a return at the end of your 1st function in 2nd example,  so that the promise is returned after resolving it?  you may not be returning it.

Comment: If you promisify the module the async methods already return promise objects so you do not need to create a promise manually.  Also when using a promise inside a then statement you need to return it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see my comments. you should do something more like the following. since you have promisified mongoose the async methods already return promises so you dont need to create a new promise to resolve or reject them. also you need to return any code that returns a promise inside a then statement.

```
router.route('/:name')
.get(function (req, res, next) {
    var values = [];
    Tag.findOneAsync({'name': req.params.name}, {urlId: 1, _id: 0}).then(function (data) {
        return promise.each(data['urlId'], function (urlId) {
            return Urls.findByIdAsync(urlId).then(function (result) {
                values.push(result);
            });
        });
    })
    .then(function () {
        res.send(values);
        //return next();    
    })
    .caught(function (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err);
        //return next();
    });
});
```

or more cleanly using promise.map

```
var mongoose = require( 'mongoose' );
var Promise = require('bluebird');
Promise.promisifyAll( mongoose );

router.route('/:name')
.get(function (req, res, next) {
    Tag.findOneAsync({'name': req.params.name}, {urlId: 1, _id: 0}).then(function (data) {
        return Promise.map(data['urlId'], function (urlId) {
            return Urls.findByIdAsync(urlId).then(function (result) {
                return result;
            });
        });
    })
    .then(function (values) {
        res.send(values);
        //return next();    
    })
    .caught(function (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err);
        //return next();
    });
});
```

Comment: Now its throwing 500 error "Error: Can't set headers after they are sent."

Comment: do you have another send statement somewhere after the caught statement in your get? maybe try `res.send(500, err)` instead of `res.status(500).send(err)` all of your sends need to be contained inside the promise methods since the async methods will execute and move to the next code block before they have resolved.

Comment: No I don't have another send statement

Comment: can you remove the caught statement and see if an error is being thrown and troubleshoot from there. the error you are getting is usually when an attempt to send a result happens after it has already been sent.

Comment: after removing caught statement, there is a new error `Unhandled rejection ReferenceError: promise is not defined`

Comment: `promise` is whatever variable you have required bluebird with so you might have it as `Promise`. see my updated second example

Comment: Thank u so much. Now its all working. I fixed the issue `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.` after removing `return next()` statement .

Comment: i see, that probable means that next is not a 3rd argument and that it was throwing a 'next is not a function' error after it already sent the response which would move to the caught block where it would try to send the response again and give you the original error. glad it all worked out